# ESLint TypeScript Interface Spread Opreator

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I recently installed ESLint into my TypeScript project and it is doing a great job. However, I have run into a bit of a predicament. I have an interface for a `RunFunction` that is a core part of implementing my Discord bot. I used to have `unknown` as `any`. However, I changed this with recommendation by ESLint. Now, however, I am unsure how to make the casting error go away in the implementation:

```
Type '(client: Bot, info: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'RunFunction'.
  Types of parameters 'info' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Here are the source files I am using:

**RunFunctionStorage.ts**

```js
import Bot from '../client/Client';

export default interface RunFunction {
    (client: Bot, ...args: unknown[]): Promise<void>;
}
```

**WarnEvent.ts**

```js
import Bot from '../../client/Client';
import RunFunction from '../../interfaces/RunFunctionStorage';

export const run: RunFunction = async (
    client: Bot,
    info: string
): Promise<void> => {
    client.logger.info(info);
};

export const name = 'warn';
```

**ReadyEvent.ts**

```js
export const run: RunFunction = async (
    client: Bot,
    message: Message
): Promise<void> => {
    ...
}

...
```

Through my research on StackOverflow, I know I am able to simply have `unknown` as the type for `info`. My issue with that solution, however, is that it would make me unaware of the type in the hints that VSCode offers me. I also looked into `info: string | unknown` but that seems to vague for me. Is there a more elegant solution to the problem?

Comment: should it not be  `export type RunFunction = ( client: Bot, ...args: unknown[]) => Promise<void>` instead? Given the way you are using it? Besides you can still make `info: unknown` and later convert it into a string inside a method, if that's doable :)

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Yes, you are totally right and that is possible. However, I would not get the benefits of TypeScript if I did it that way. VSCode would not be able to provide me, via Intellisense, the number of arguments I should pass the function if I used `...args: unknown[]` or what type `info` should be if I did `info: unknown`.

Comment: i wonder if the `extends` keyword on the interfaces can help... let me search a little on this

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar What is your thought regarding using the `extends` keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not overthink it. There are a couple of ways to handle this

### First

The easiest way to fix it is using a built in interface called

#### CallableFunction

You just need to use it like this

```js
export const run: CallableFunction = // yow function
```

The problem with that is, your run function won’t show you what parameter it needs, good thing of it is you can pass what ever u want

### Second

create your own type

```js
export type RunFunction = <T,R>(client: Bot, info:T) => Promise<R>
```

## Solution

This can be done with a generics

```js
export default interface RunFunction<T> {
    (client: Bot, ...args: T): Promise<void>;
}
```

That simple T is a placeholder per say, it will be what ever you want it to be for instance if you need to pass a single string you have to specified like this

```js
/// for functions and stuff I prefer types, I only use interfaces for objs or classes 

export type RunFunction =<T> (bot: Bot, params: T)=>Promise<void>;


And now that I think you don’t even need that, you can create the function directly 

function runFunction <T>(boy:Bot, params:T) {
//Yow code

}
…
/// here you are saying list is an array of strings
runFunction<string[]>(instance, list)

// here is an object 
unFunction<string[]>(instance, list)

Now when you call the function you’ll get type hints
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these solutions solve the problem I am facing. The first one, as you mentioned, would not show the needed parameters. The second is too solid for use.

Comment: So what’s good, both! Did you found a solution ? I kind of gave you the answer heating for you to catch it .

Comment: So your edit there with the generics seems to be the only other way than disabling the ESLint error message for that specific line. I think that I prefer this method though so I will be giving it a shot later.

Answer (score 0):

@Mahyar Mirrashed,

Unfortunately, the closest I got is :

```
export default interface RunFunction<R extends unknown> {
  (client: Bot, ...args: R[] ): Promise<void>
}
```

```
export const run: RunFunction<string> = async (
    client: Bot,
    info: string
): Promise<void> => {}


export const fly: RunFunction<Message> = async (client: Bot, info: Message): Promise<void> => {}
```

This is very close to what you want in the VSCode / Typescript Intellisense, but it isn't exactly what you want. You'll see an array in the suggestions rather an the single object.

The other workaround I found is :

```
export default interface RunFunction<R extends unknown[]> {
  (client: Bot, ...args: R ): Promise<void>
}


export const run: RunFunction<[string]> = async (
    client: Bot,
    info
): Promise<void> => {
  
}

export const fly: RunFunction<[Message]> = async (client: Bot, info): Promise<void> => {}
```

This one is even more close to what you want, but it modifies the 2nd argument to `arg_0, arg_1` instead of the name that you kept in such as `info`